# Can sea units have more then the given amount in Axis and Allies 1941?

Tags: axis-and-allies

So I'm currently in a game where my opponent has 5 battle ships using the circle grey markers, and I have 4 battle ships.

Is this legal? or is only each faction allowed 2 battleships? what about other sea units?

Answer (score 2):

Unlike Monopoly, in which the rules restrict players to 32 houses and 12 hotels (in total), the number of pieces in Axis and Allies are limited only by what you can build according to the rules.

The number of pieces given in the games are based on the most common number of pieces in play. But feel free to play outside the parameters indicated by the "equipment," and by all means, substitute your own markers or tokens for the extra pieces you need.